# Pros and cons of lightweight front end applications calling HTTP web services

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, web-services, api

My development team and I are traditional .NET developers writing and maintaining many applications structured in C# .NET web forms (aspx pages) and more recently MVC 5.  We've recently stood up a new MVC based API which acts as a web service for serving up parameter-requested data in JSON and serving this data in a consumable form.

I'm very interested in pursuing lightweight web applications going forward where all of the heavy lifting would take place in the API and the application itself would be a collection of basic web pages.  We went down the path of using an MVC solution written in Visual Studio to consume the API but that we started bumping up against our old habits, writing business logic in the app itself, fragmenting each application, etc.

My question to you all is what types of functionality are fully lost when moving to a lightweight front end web application (HTML pages) consuming a JSON producing web API?  I imagine security would be a challenge since today our C# apps rely on the Active Directory account of the web user.  What other items will stand in our way?  Our web applications are for relatively basic, that is calling and displaying lists of data objects, viewing/editing/creating individual objects, reporting etc.  We're trying to get away from the complex re-work that comes with each new web application (we have over 60 currently).  We're trying to centralize and I love the idea of APIs and lightweight web front ends.

It would be great to use something like AngularJS to consume the service, deserialize the objects and write them to modern Bootstrappped HTML pages.  Ideally we wouldn't even maintain classes and objects in the web app (of course they would be in the API) but we would just expect a defined list of object attributes and would place them on the page where needed.  And on the creates and updates we can post data back by deserializing the data from the HTML form and pushing back to the API.

Is this possible?  What stands in our way?  What will we miss most from the world of C#, code behinds, ASPX, and cshtml/html helpers?  What is not possible in this basic HTML/web API platform?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a big question.

It sounds like your dev team is welcoming in some new technology with open arms, and you like what you see. Good first step (: But it's clear that there are still plenty of hurdles to overcome, and ways to improve the development process (an ongoing battle for all teams). You mentioned:

1. Business logic in the presentation layer
2. Fragmentation + general bad habits

These seem like a tangent from your main question, but are good questions. Have you considered [Code Reviews](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_review) as part of the workflow for accepting pull requests into your version control? Do you have code standards such as DRY, KISS, etc. that can be used to objectively measure these pull requests? And do you have a clearly defined architecture in place (like [Onion Architecture](http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/the-onion-architecture-part-1/)) so that all code has a clear place where it lives in the code?

Back to your main questions:

1. Security (namely active directory)
2. Reusable code (mostly use lists and data objects [basic crud])
3. Don't want to maintain classes/objects in webapp
4. Limitations? Can we do what we want?

I am by no means a Senior .NET Developer, so maybe someone else can offer better thoughts, but here are mine:

I think you will find very few limitations, but it will require you and your team to tackle new problems that many of you may not have experience with.

You mention not using models (just properties), but I would push you in the other direction. Application's I work with generally have the following:

- Domain Objects (Model your DB)
- Data Transfer Objects (DTOs)
- View Models (comprised of DTOs and view model properties)

With all three being maintained in the code behind, and the transfer from Domain -> DTO and back being facilitated with AutoMapper.

We also recognized that the majority of our apps were comprised of basic CRUD operations on key Domain Objects. So... We created a base view model that had a List and a DetailDto (form/single object), where each object that we operate CRUD on acts as a SPA.

For security, we use [authorization filters and the identity project](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/authentication-and-authorization-in-aspnet-web-api). This gets us the level of security we need, but it sounds like you have additional concerns that I'm woefully unqualified to answer.

We still use helpers, especially for complex components, but we've built them in such a way that they work well with our front end data-binding framework.

A bit rambly. Feel free to ask for clarification or additional questions. Hope this helps at least a little!

Answer (score 1):

One thing that comes to my mind is re usability. With MVC you can have partial views to organize your repeating code blocks. Though you could achieve something with Angular, It may not be fully possible With plain HTML pages.